# Function within Function in R

Tags: r

Can you please explain to me why the code complains saying that `Samdat` is not found?

I am trying to switch between models, so I declared a function that contains these specific models and I just need to call this function as one of the argument in the `get.f` function where the resampling will change the structure for each design matrix in the model. The code complains that `Samdat` is not found when it is found.

Also, is there a way I can make the conditional statement `if(Model == M1())` instead of having to create another argument `M` to set `if(M==1)`?

Here is my code:

```
dat <-  cbind(Y=rnorm(20),rnorm(20),runif(20),rexp(20),rnorm(20),runif(20), rexp(20),rnorm(20),runif(20),rexp(20))
nam <- paste("v",1:9,sep="")
colnames(dat) <- c("Y",nam)

M1 <- function(){
    a1 = cbind(Samdat[,c(2:5,7,9)])
    b1 = cbind(Samdat[,c(2:4,6,8,7)])
    c1 = b1+a1
    list(a1=a1,b1=b1,c1=c1)}

M2 <- function(){
    a1= cbind(Samdat[,c(2:5,7,9)])+2
    b1= cbind(Samdat[,c(2:4,6,8,7)])+2
    c1 = a1+b1
    list(a1=a1,b1=b1,c1=c1)}

M3 <- function(){
    a1= cbind(Samdat[,c(2:5,7,9)])+8
    b1= cbind(Samdat[,c(2:4,6,8,7)])+8
    c1 = a1+b1
    list(a1=a1,b1=b1,c1=c1)}
#################################################################
get.f <- function(asim,Model,M){
    sse <-c()
    for(i in 1:asim){
        set.seed(i)
        Samdat <- dat[sample(1:nrow(dat),nrow(dat),replace=T),]
        Y <- Samdat[,1]
        if(M==1){
            a2 <- Model$a1
            b2 <- Model$b1
            c2 <- Model$c1
            s<- a2+b2+c2
            fit <- lm(Y~s)
            cof <- sum(summary(fit)$coef[,1])
            coff <-Model$cof
            sse <-c(sse,coff)
        }
        else if(M==2){
            a2 <- Model$a1
            b2 <- Model$b1
            c2 <- Model$c1
            s<- c2+12
            fit <- lm(Y~s)
            cof <- sum(summary(fit)$coef[,1])
            coff <-Model$cof
            sse <-c(sse,coff)
        }
        else {
            a2 <- Model$a1
            b2 <- Model$b1
            c2 <- Model$c1
            s<- c2+a2
            fit <- lm(Y~s)
            cof <- sum(summary(fit)$coef[,1])
            coff <- Model$cof
            sse <-c(sse,coff)
        }
    }
    return(sse)
}

get.f(10,Model=M1(),M=1)
get.f(10,Model=M2(),M=2)
get.f(10,Model=M3(),M=3)
```

Comment: Could you please reindent your code to see where functions start and end? Maybe that will also help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I separated with a line space, what do you mean by reindent

Comment: What I meant was exactly what Jilber did for you.

Comment: It wasn't me who did the indentation, it was @themel, credits go for him. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call

```
get.f(10, Model=M1(), M=1)
```

your `M1` function is immediately called. It dies because inside the body of `M1` you are using `Samdat` which is only defined later, in the body of `get.f`.

Somehow, you need to call `M1` *after* `Samdat` is defined. One way of doing that is to make `M1` (the function) an argument to `get.f` and call the function from inside `get.f`:

```
get.f <- function(asim, Model.fun, M) {
   ...
   Sambat <- ...
   Model  <- Model.fun()
   ...
}
get.f(10, Model.fun = M1, M=1)
```

Also, in general, it is bad programming to use global variables, i.e., make your function use variables that are defined outside their scope. Instead, it is recommended that everything a function uses be passed as input arguments. You have two such cases in your code: `M1` (`M2`, and `M3`) use `Samdat` and `get.f` uses `dat`. They should be arguments to your functions. Here is a nicer version of your code. I have not fixed everything, so you'll have to do a little more to get it to work:

```
M1 <- function(sampled.data) {
   a1 <- sampled.data[, c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v6", "v8")]
   b1 <- sampled.data[, c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v5", "v7", "v6")]
   c1 <- a1 + b1
   list(a1 = a1, b1 = b1, c1 = c1)
}

get.f <- function(dat, asim, Model.fun, offset, M) {
   sse <- c()
   for(i in 1:asim){
      set.seed(i)
      Samdat <- dat[sample(1:nrow(dat), nrow(dat), replace = TRUE), ]
      Y      <- Samdat[, "Y"]
      Model  <- Model.fun(sampled.data = Samdat)
      a2     <- Model$a1
      b2     <- Model$b1
      c2     <- Model$c1      
      s      <- switch(M, a2 + b2 + c2, c2 + 12, c2 + a2)
      fit    <- lm(Y ~ s)
      cof    <- sum(summary(fit)$coef[,1])
      coff   <- Model$cof        # there is a problem here...
      sse    <- c(sse, coff)     # this is not efficient
   }
   return(sse)
}

dat <- cbind(Y = rnorm(20), v1 = rnorm(20), v2 = runif(20), v3 = rexp(20),
                            v4 = rnorm(20), v5 = runif(20), v6 = rexp(20),
                            v7 = rnorm(20), v8 = runif(20), v9 = rexp(20))

get.f(dat, 10, Model.fun = M1, M = 1)
```

One last thing that jumps out: if the definition of `s` (what I gathered under `switch()` is related to the `Model` you use, then consider merging the definitions of `Model` and `s` together: add `s` to the list output of your `M1`, `M2`, `M3` functions so that `s` can just be defined as `s <- Model$s`, and you can then drop the `M` input to `get.f`.

Answer (score 12):

You might want to have a look at the [R scoping rules](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Scope-of-variables). In particular, there's no reason to expect that variables you define in a function are visible in other functions.

You might be confused because the global environment (i.e. the top-level outside all functions) is an exception from this rule. I'm not going to go into your other questions, but let me note that the entire script looks very messed up to me - i.e. `M1` to `M3` are essentially one function, and the wad of copy/paste in `get.f` is definitely terrible. Whatever it is that you're trying to do can definitely be written in a less convoluted way.

Let's have a look at the `M`s first - why not one function with a parameter? Including the solution to your scope problem, that makes two parameters -

```
M <- function(sampleData, offset) { 
    a1 = sampleData[,c(2:5,7,9)] + offset
    b1 = sampleData[,c(2:4,6,8,7)] + offset
    c1 = b1+a1
    list(a1=a1,b1=b1,c1=c1)
}
```

If you insist on defining aliases, you can also do something like

```
M1 <- function(sampleData) M(sampleData, 0) 
M2 <- function(sampleData) M(sampleData, 2) 
M3 <- function(sampleData) M(sampleData, 8)
```

This is already less repetitive, but ideally you want the computer to do the repetition for you ([DRY!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

```
offsets <- c(0,2,8)
Models <- sapply(offsets, FUN=function(offset) function(sampleData) M(sampleData, offset))
```

Looking at `get.f`, it's not quite clear what you're trying to do - you're trying to fit something and collect something from the results, but the part about `Model$cof` refers to an undefined variable (your `Model` just has `a1`,`b1` and `c1` entries). Assuming you want to actually collect `cof` and discarding the interim code, `get.f` probably looks like this:

```
M <- function(sampleData, offset) { 
    a1 = sampleData[,c(2:5,7,9)] + offset
    b1 = sampleData[,c(2:4,6,8,7)] + offset
    c1 = b1+a1
    list(a1=a1,b1=b1,c1=c1)
}

get.f <- function(asim,Model,M){
    sse <-c()
    for(i in 1:asim){
        set.seed(i)
        Samdat <- dat[sample(1:nrow(dat),nrow(dat),replace=T),]
        Y <- Samdat[,1]
        model <- Model()
        if(M==1){
            a2 <- model$a1
            b2 <- model$b1
            c2 <- model$c1
            s<- a2+b2+c2
            fit <- lm(Y~s)
            cof <- sum(summary(fit)$coef[,1])
            sse <-c(sse,cof)
        }
        else if(M==2){
            a2 <- model$a1
            b2 <- model$b1
            c2 <- model$c1
            s<- c2+12
            fit <- lm(Y~s)
            cof <- sum(summary(fit)$coef[,1])
            sse <-c(sse,cof)
        }
        else {
            a2 <- model$a1
            b2 <- model$b1
            c2 <- model$c1
            s<- c2+a2
            fit <- lm(Y~s)
            cof <- sum(summary(fit)$coef[,1])
            sse <-c(sse,cof)
        }
    }
    return(sse)
}


get.f(10,Model=M1,M=1) 
get.f(10,Model=M2,M=2)
get.f(10,Model=M3,M=3)
```

That's still terribly repetitive, so why don't we think about it for a minute? All you're doing with your samples is to calculate one column from them to use in your fit. I don't see why you need to do the calculation in an `M` function and then do the extraction of the single value in `get.f` (dependent on which particular M you were using) - this seems indicative that the extraction should much rather be part of M... but if you need to keep them separate, okay, let's use separate extraction functions. Still comes in under half of your code size in reasonably-written R:

```
# Set up test data
dat <-  cbind(Y=rnorm(20),rnorm(20),runif(20),rexp(20),rnorm(20),runif(20), rexp(20),rnorm(20),runif(20),rexp(20))
nam <- paste("v",1:9,sep="")
colnames(dat) <- c("Y",nam)

# calculate a1..c1 from a sample
M <- function(sampleData, offset) { 
    a1 = sampleData[,c(2:5,7,9)] + offset
    b1 = sampleData[,c(2:4,6,8,7)] + offset
    c1 = b1+a1
    list(a1=a1,b1=b1,c1=c1)
}

# create a fixed-offset model from the variable offset model by fixing offset
makeModel <- function(offset) function(sampleData) M(sampleData, offset)   

# run model against asim subsamples of data and collect coefficients
get.f <- function(asim,model,expected) 
    sapply(1:asim,  function (i){
        set.seed(i)
        Samdat <- dat[sample(1:nrow(dat),nrow(dat),replace=T),]
        Y <- Samdat[,1]
        s <- expected(model(Samdat))
        fit <- lm(Y~s)
        sum(summary(fit)$coef[,1])
    })

# list of models to run and how to extract the expectation values from the model reslts
todo <- list(
        list(model=makeModel(0), expected=function(data) data$a1+data$b1+data$c1),
        list(model=makeModel(2), expected=function(data) data$c1+12),
        list(model=makeModel(8), expected=function(data) data$c1+data$a1))

sapply(todo, function(l) { get.f(10, l$model, l$expected)})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I tried to create an example similar to what I am trying to do.  First: the function M1-M3 are similar but are not the same, I added different constant to each one. However in the actual job I am coding they have different matrices. What I am trying to do is call these functions (M1-M3) in get.f function to create the new matrices with M1-M3. I would do this after sampling the data so I can fit the new model. I don't understand what is the terrible part you are talking about. I have more than M1-M3 (there are M1-M30) so I can't just code them in get.f function.

Comment: Hi @themel, I have created 3 scripts in r. The 1st is for sampling the data and creates different matrices for the sampled data. Then in the 2nd script I created the model functions (M1-M3) that compined different matrices and check some results. The 3rd script I created the get.f to fit different models based on these different matrices in the 2nd script. My main objective is to achieve SSE results. I have around 3000 columns